# hide the dynamic created radio button component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click in one of the table cells, radio buttons appear. when i click on other cell and select the option, radio button component is getting shown for the first cell which should not be shown/displayed.Please suggest where i'm going wrong.

Sample code below:

```
function showData(index, id, name){
    var rOptions = document.getElementById("options");
    if (rOptions == null){
      //logic
}       

   $('.one').live('click', function() {
     if($(this).hasClass("one")) {       
        deselect(index, name);  
     } 
 });
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

you are adding an event listener everytime you're clicking on your cell.

You could use $(app).die(); and $('.one').die(); to erase the listeners every time but I would recommend refactoring some code.

You should be consistent in use of your selectors...either use jquery or don't.

Also pull out your eventListener Attachment.

```
$("[id^=app]").on('click', function(event) {
    console.log("This is my name: "+this.name);
});
```

should do the trick. You can use an encoded ID to store your ID, name and whatever and parse them when the event happens so that you have one generic event for all cells.

You should also consider using a newer version of jquery.